# iOS segue from DetailViewController when Link is clicked in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, storyboard, segue

I'm building a Master-Detail App.
In the Detail-View a UIWebView displays html-content based on what is selected in the master. Since this html also includes links, I want to open these links in another View (a uiwebview with the possiblity of going back, reloading, etc. - a browser pretty much).

I've set my DetailViewController to be a UIWebViewDelegate in DetailViewController.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>
```

In DetailViewController.m's

```
- (void)configureView
```

(detailHtml is the UIWebView that displays said HTML content) I do

```
self.detailHtml.delegate = self;
```

Further on I have the function that gets triggered when a link is clicked

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openCustomBrowser" sender:self];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Connecting the segue to the detail view controller instead of the navigation controller doesn't work either.
The Storyboard:
http://s27.postimg.org/9hpgpmf1e/Bildschirmfoto_2014_03_11_um_18_02_19.jpg

I get the following error:

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: 
delegate: <NSUnknownKeyException> [<BrowserViewController 0x8a5b120> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key reload.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need puth inRequest as sender.
But why you need create new view controller? You can go back from thats UIWebView with `goBack` method. Just add corresponding button in toolbar or navigationItem.

Comment: Using inRequest as sender doesn't work (I don't think the sender is the problem, setting it to nil doesn't work either).

I want to use a new view, because for the usual detail-view I want the view to look different (i.e. I don't want the toolbar with those buttons, etc.)

Comment: @KevinGrabher, of course just setting other object as setter will not fork. You need rewrite prepareForSegue... to use NSURLRequest as sender. Do you sinked about how yours new viewcontroller will know which page it should load. And add `reload` method in `BrowserViewController` to get know who and why calling nonexisting method of yours viewcontroller.

Comment: i would do something like the following, but it seems my problem happens before it even comes to this, no?
Even after checking out several tutorials I can't seem to find what's causing the error.

`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"openCustomBrowser"]) {
        BrowserViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.htmlTest = @"<b>test</b>";
    }
}`

Comment: @KevinGrabher, try reload `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` and set breakpoint inside it to see where it's performed.

Comment: The problem has not been the segue but one of the buttons in the new view. I removed all buttons from the bottom bar and now the segue works fine (somebody punch me in the face please?).
Thanks so much for your time and help.